# Where are Syslog remote messages stored?

Tags: linux, bash, syslog, rc

I have a client/server setup inside my organization. I was looking on the server side in `/etc/rc.sysinit` file and found this:

[image]

Clearly, Syslog messages from server side are being redirected to the client side on IP=$LPIP and port 514.

My question is where can I find these syslog messages on the client side (in which file)? `/var/log/syslog` on both machine store local messages only.

Comment: The remote system needs to be configured to *receive* remote syslog messages.  The final disposition of those messages depends on which syslog server you're using and how it is configured.  Traditional syslogd is configured via `/etc/syslog.conf`, but other servers use other config files.

Comment: This is actually an embedded system, I read somewhere that syslog on busybox does not use `/etc/syslog.conf`. Also I had a look at local `/etc/syslog.conf` on client side and it does not seem to have any config for remote msgs.

Comment: server even does not have any `/etc/syslog.conf`

Comment: You need to confirm what syslog daemon this is and then read its documentation.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more? It may be something trivial but I dint get it. How do I confirm which syslog deamon it is ?